# Ignoring case, punctuation, and whitespace in Strings

Tags: python, filter, state, slice

What is the most efficient way of ignoring case, punctuation, and whitespace in strings? These strings should be divided into words instead of characters should ignore the aforementioned details on comparisons, and slices of these word-strings should be as efficient as possible with speed in mind.

I was going to use case and punctuation insensitive strings for the following code, but after seeing how long it would take to evaluate `class Slice: def __eq__(self, other): return self.root == other.root`, I have decided to work with `data = tuple(string.split())` instead. Having strings that are insensitive to case, punctuation, and spacing and that work over words instead of characters was too expensive into the computationally expensive algorithms already expressed in the code below.

```
class Slice:

    def __init__(self, data, offset, length):
        self.prefix = data[:offset]
        self.root = data[offset:offset+length]
        self.suffix = data[offset+length:]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.root == other.root

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.root)

################################################################################

class Match:

    def __init__(self, data, key, prefix_tree, suffix_tree):
        self.data = data
        self.key = key
        self.prefix_tree = prefix_tree
        self.suffix_tree = suffix_tree
        self.__value = len(key) + prefix_tree.value() + suffix_tree.value()

    def value(self):
        return self.__value

################################################################################

class Tree(tuple):

    def __new__(cls, nodes):
        tree = super().__new__(cls, nodes)
        tree.__value = max(map(Match.value, tree)) if tree else 0
        return tree

    def value(self):
        return self.__value

    def find(self, value):
        for index, match in enumerate(self):
            if match.value() == value:
                return index
        raise ValueError()

################################################################################

def search(data, key):
    length = 0
    nodes = []
    for d_block in shrink(data, len(key)):
        block_len = len(d_block)
        if length > block_len:
            return Tree(nodes)
        for k_block in slide(key, block_len):
            if d_block == k_block:
                length = block_len
                prefix_tree = search(d_block.prefix, k_block.prefix)
                suffix_tree = search(d_block.suffix, k_block.suffix)
                match = Match(d_block, k_block, prefix_tree, suffix_tree)
                nodes.append(match)
    return Tree(nodes)

def shrink(data, max_len):
    for length in range(min(len(data), max_len), 0, -1):
        for block in slide(data, length):
            yield block

def slide(data, length):
    for offset in range(len(data) - length + 1):
        yield Slice(data, offset, length)

################################################################################

def build_tree(nodes):
    match = nodes[nodes.find(nodes.value())]
    node = match.key
    if match.prefix_tree:
        node.prefix = build_tree(match.prefix_tree)
    if match.suffix_tree:
        node.suffix = build_tree(match.suffix_tree)
    return node

def flatten_tree(node):
    array = [0]
    _flatten(node, array)
    return tuple(array)

def _flatten(node, array):
    if isinstance(node.prefix, Slice):
        _flatten(node.prefix, array)
    else:
        array.append(node.prefix)
    array[0] += 1
    array.append((array[0], node.root))
    if isinstance(node.suffix, Slice):
        _flatten(node.suffix, array)
    else:
        array.append(node.suffix)
```

Comment: Would help if there was some context/documentation as to what the class is being used for...

Comment: Please do not use `__` for your "private" variable names.  Please use `_`: that's more common, and less strain on our brains to read your code.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"What is the best way to go about fixing this problem?"**

The best -- and only -- way is to define what this object "means" and what the length of this object "means".

The object appears to be a list of words.  Nothing more.  That seems to be the value in `_string`.

It's not clear what `_simple` is, other than an inaccessible filtered subset of the words in `_string`.

So what's the length?  The length of the words or the length of the words in the filtered subset?

Only you can define what this class **means**.  The **meaning** will then determine how to implement `__len__`.  Until you define the meaning, it's impossible to determine how anything should be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

If you want iteration on a String instance to iterate on its `self.__string`, as your `__iter__` method indicates, the only sensible choice for length is also to return the length of `__string` -- it would be *truly* peculiar if `len(x)` and `sum(1 for _ in x)` resulted in different values.

I have to admit I don't understand the purpose of this class (and in particular why you made the terrible choice of having it old-style, and why you use such a contorted way to build `__simple`), but internal consistency is important anyway.  So, either change `__iter__`, or make `__len__` logically compatible with it.

Your slicing logic also totally escapes me -- why are you building the slice's `__simple` in a way that's likely to be different from what you'd get by rebuilding it from the slice's `__string`? E.g., if `self.__string` is '?Boh!' and therefore `self.__simple` is 'boh', why would you **want** `self[1:-1]` to have a `__string` of 'Boh' but with a `__simple` of 'o', so incompatible, different, and inconsistent from the `__simple` you'd get by recomputing it from the slice...?

I guess that's not germane to this Q about length, but I'm just curious about these many, extremely peculiar design choices that you're making...

Comment: Since Python 3.0 came out, I have only been writing code in that language (currently 3.1). If you are familiar with how classes work in 3.1, then you know that this is a new-style class (all classes in Python 3.x are new-style classes). Therefore, it is unnecessary to explicitly inherit from `object`. As for how slices work, please notice this line: `self.__string = tuple(string.split())` These string objects work on words and not characters.

Comment: @Noctis, you've changed the code so drastically (I see no String class any more, for example!) that it's impossible to reconnect my comments to your current code. As for Python 3, that's great, but mentioning it in your Q would obviously be better since that's *not* what the vast majority of Python users are using today;-).